# google maps v3 adding an info window to a circle

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

Is there a way to add a infoWindow to a circle created by  google.maps.Circle

something like this

```
var circ = new google.maps.Circle({
            center:latlng,
            clickable:false,
            fillColor:colors[count],
            fillOpacity:0.3, 
            map:map,
            radius:radius,
            strokeColor:colors[count],
            strokeOpacity:0.3});
```

and

```
//create info window
var infoWindow= new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Your info here"
    });

//add a click event to the circle
google.maps.event.addListener(circ, 'click', function(){
//call  the infoWindow
infoWindow.open(map, circ);
});
```

or alternatively is there a way to create an invisible marker at the center of the circle that can be clicked on to access an infoWindow

Comment: or alternatively is there a way to create an invisible marker at the center of the circle that can be clicked on to access an infoWindow

Answer (score 46, accepted):

you can have info window for your circle overlay. But you have to slightly adjust your code.

First, it is necessary to set `clickable=true` for your Circle overlay (otherwise click events on the circle are not processed).

Then you have to change the code of the click listener. Putting circle as a parameter to function open() has no effect (Circle is not the proper kind of MVCObject, for explanation read documentation of [InfoWindow](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindow).open() function). To display the info window you have to provide its position - e.g. position of the click event, center of the circle, ....

The code is then

```
google.maps.event.addListener(circ, 'click', function(ev){
    infoWindow.setPosition(ev.latLng);
    infoWindow.open(map);
});
```

or

```
google.maps.event.addListener(circ, 'click', function(ev){
    infoWindow.setPosition(circ.getCenter());
    infoWindow.open(map);
});
```

*Answer to your comment*:
You can create a trick with an invisible marker (just put fully transparent image as the marker icon), but I would prefer solution with Circle overlay.

Comment: what does ev represent? and is there a way to an indicator to the user to click the circle like the "title" option in a marker

Comment: ev is MouseEvent (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MouseEvent). Circle overlay doesn't have any textual indicator. But when clickable is true the cursor changes when it's positioned over the circle. Creating textual indicator is not that simple - I would do such thing with custom overlay and circle's mouseover event listener.

Comment: I have tried this method but it did not work. I receive the click event but I cannot open the infoWindow! do you have any other hint?

Comment: Just to say that if you're generating circles in a loop then instead of "infoWindow.setPosition(circ.getCenter());" you should use "infoWindow.setPosition(this.getCenter());".  Otherwise you're info window will always pop up by the last circle in the loop.

Comment: its only works on last lat lang of circle for me.i have an array of lat lang and generate few circle.how can i determine each circle's content ?

Comment: update:i hv found the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538075/adding-info-windows-to-multiple-circle-overlays. =)

Answer (score 2):

to set info window at where mouse clicked

```
google.maps.event.addListener(circ, 'click', function(ev){
    infoWindow.setPosition(ev.latLng); //<-- ev matches what you put ^ (mouse event)
    infoWindow.open(map);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same confusion. I simply solved it using

const circle = new google.maps.Circle({
strokeColor: "#FFFF00",
strokeOpacity: 0.8,
strokeWeight: 1,
fillColor: "#FFFF00",
fillOpacity: 0.4,
center: position,    // { lat: 46.021667, lng: 11.124717 }
radius: distance,
map: map,

```
    });

    const info = "Radius: " + circle.getRadius() + "m";
    const iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: info,
        position: position,
    });
    circle.addListener("mouseover", () => {
        iw.open({
            map,
        });
    });
    circle.addListener("mouseout", () => {
        iw.close();
    });
    circle.addListener("click", () => {
        circle.setMap(null);
    });
```