# Google Maps JS API v3 Single marker Multiple circles

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

Screenshot: http://imageshack.us/a/img59/8541/72825985.png

The above result is delivered by multiple markers(with different radius) on same spot.

I would like to drag a single marker at one time, not multiple markers.

Second, the infowindow is made available for different radius.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
var locations = [
  ['US gov suggested', 1.8833, 102.7833, 5, 'green', 80000],
  ['agricultural contamination', 1.8833, 102.7833, 4, 'blue', 60000],
  ['Chernobyl_Exclusion_Zone (fallout)', 1.8833, 102.7833, 3, 'yellow', 30000],
  ['Fukushima evacuation zone', 1.8833, 102.7833, 2, 'red', 20000],
  ['emergency zone', 1.8833, 102.7833, 1, 'black', 5000]

];
```

and

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    draggable: true,
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      fillColor:locations[i][4],
      //fillOpacity:0.3, 
      //strokeColor:locations[i][4],
      strokeOpacity:0.1,
      //strokeWeight:1,
      radius: locations[i][5] // 30 km
});

circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');

}
```

References:
[Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/circle-overlay/circle-overlay.html?r=67

http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/google-maps-v3-shortcode-multiple-markers/trunk/

Answer (score 2):

Create as much circles as you want to and bind the `center`-property of each circle to the `position`-property of the marker by using the method [`bindTo()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MVCObject) of the circles

Answer (score 1):

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

var marker, i;
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]),
  draggable: true,
  map: map
  });

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  

  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    clickable:true,
    fillColor:locations[i][4],
    //fillOpacity:0.3, 
    //strokeColor:locations[i][4],
    strokeOpacity:0.1,
    //strokeWeight:1,
    radius: locations[i][5] // 30 km
  });

circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
```

Secondly, it not easy to add [infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infowindow) for multiple circle overlays. Any ideas or hints? For example, http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/8198/overlap.jpg

Reference:[google maps v3 adding an info window to a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584358/google-maps-v3-adding-an-info-window-to-a-circle)