# Adding info windows to multiple circle overlays

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am having trouble adding an info window to each one of multiple circle overlays.
When I click on a circle an info window appears, but not on the circle I clicked but rather on the last circle added. It seems that each time the loop executes the event listener is added to every circle but the content of the info window is derived from the last circle added.

```
for (i in cityPoints) {
    var magnitudeOptions = {
        map: map,
        center: cityPoints[i].center,
        radius: cityPoints[i].magnitude,
        id:cityPoints[i].id,
        addr:cityPoints[i].addr,
        infoWindowIndex: i
     };
     cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(magnitudeOptions);
     circlesArray.push(cityCircle);
     infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: cityPoints[i].id + " " + cityPoints[i].addr });
     infoWindowsArray.push(infoWindow);
     google.maps.event.addListener(circlesArray[i], 'click', function (ev) {
         infoWindowsArray[i].setPosition(cityPoints[i].center);
         infoWindowsArray[i].open(map);
     });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the i parameter you pass is the last, always. 
Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Circles</title>
    <style>
    #map-canvas {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>

// Create an object containing LatLng, population.
var cityPoints = {};
cityPoints[0] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878113, -87.629798),
  id: 0,
  addr: 'avenue0',
  magnitude: 100000
};
cityPoints[1] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714352, -74.005973),
  id: 1, 
  addr: 'avenue1',
  magnitude: 100000
};
cityPoints[2] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -118.243684),
  id: 2,
  addr: 'avenue2',
  magnitude: 100000
}
var cityCircle;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();  

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

for (i in cityPoints) {
           var magnitudeOptions = {
                map: map,
                center: cityPoints[i].center,
                radius: cityPoints[i].magnitude,
                id:cityPoints[i].id,
                addr:cityPoints[i].addr,
                infoWindowIndex: i
            };
   cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(magnitudeOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'click', (function(cityCircle, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(cityPoints[i].id + " " + cityPoints[i].addr);
            infoWindow.setPosition(cityCircle.getCenter());
            infoWindow.open(map);
        }
      })(cityCircle, i));
}
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Partially worked.. When the map loads all the info windows open without even clicking. If I close an info window I can't open it again by clicking on the circle.

Comment: Re Alki! You use infoWindowsArray without having pushed anything to it. The problem is that I have to reference somehow to the circle i am clicking and this is not possible because cityCircle is updated every time the loop executes although the circles remain on the map. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Still wont work. I tried different ways and still nothing. 
Is all comes down to getting a reference to the circle that is clicked

Comment: tq..really usefull for me!! =)

Comment: @alkis the updated code allow 1 info window open only.if i click other circle, the previous info window auto close.can you advice how should i change the code so it only close after i click close button. because some time i want to see several info window. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is called [closure](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure), and google has information about how to do it with markers. Below is how to do it with circles. 
In the code, "locations" is an array containing all of the latitudes and longitudes that I want to plot as circles.

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  currentLocation = locations[i].latlng;
  var currentLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(currentLocation[0]),parseFloat(currentLocation[1]) )

  var newCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: currentLatLng,
    radius:10000,
    strokeColor:"#0000FF",
    strokeOpacity:0.8,
    strokeWeight:2,
    fillColor:"#0000FF",
    fillOpacity:0.4,
    map:map,
    clickable:true,
  });

  attachSecretMessage(locations[i].instname+', Tuition: $'+locations[i].tuitionfee02_tf) 

}


function attachSecretMessage(tuitionInfo){

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: tuitionInfo,
    position: currentLatLng
  });

  myCity.addListener('click', function() {
     infowindow.open(map);
  });
}
```